# WPF add TabItem with behavior programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In xaml when I want to add some behavior I do like this:

```xml
<!-- XAML -->
<TabItem behaviors:TabItemValidationBehavior.ActivateValidation ="True">
<TabItem.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Header"                   
               Foreground="{Binding Path=(behavior:TabItemBehavior.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" />
    </TabItem.Header>
</TabItem>
```

It is possible to do the same programmatically?

```cs
// C#
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
??tab.AddBehavior(behaviors:TabItemValidationBehavior.ActivateValidation(True));??
??tab.Header= new TextBlock { Foreground.BindTo(behavior:TabItemBehavior.Foreground, tab) };??
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior exposes an AttachedProperty. You can set it like

```
TabItem tab = new TabItem();
TabItemValidationBehavior.SetActivateValidation(tab, true);

TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(TabItemBehavior.ForegroundProperty);
binding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource{Mode = RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, AncestorType = typeof(TabItem)};

text.SetBinding(TextBlock.ForegroundProperty, binding);

tab.Header=text;
```

Comment: Thank You, works fine. I was far far away from solution ;)